# how to insert in to db when number is having digits greater than m for number(m,n) in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

in DB which i do not have privilege to alter.
a column has number(13,4) and how is it possible to insert 999999999999999999 whose length is more than 13 ? It is throwing exception. Is it possible to convert in to 1.23e3 format and does the db save this format?

Comment: I dont think so its possible.. may be through some mathematical calculation you can find some workaround.. but not recommended..

Answer (score 0):

no it is not possible because of the rules and limitations you mentioned yourself. The column has that formatting, you cannot change it so you cannot make it fit. period

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to insert a number, which is greater than the specified precision and scale of the column.

You have to change the database.

If you don't have permissions to alter the table then simply ask someone who does; you have a valid "business" need to do so.

I would highly recommend not working out some way to "hack" around this limitation. Constraints such as this exist to enforce data quality. Though maybe misapplied in this situation, putting data in two different formats in the same column makes it immeasurably more difficult to retrieve data from the database. Hence why you should always store numbers as numbers etc.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately not. There is no way how to achieve this.